# Rest Kit nested array - taking just one element

Tags: ios, json, swift, restkit

I have problem with Rest Kit and i haven't yet found an answer.
Basically i have JSON:
http://pastebin.com/3UBXUy3A
and mapping:

```
    let artistMapping = RKObjectMapping(forClass: Artist.self)
    artistMapping.addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary(["name": "name", "playcount": "playCount"])
    let responseDescriptor = RKResponseDescriptor(mapping: artistMapping, method: RKRequestMethod.GET, pathPattern: "/2.0", keyPath: "topartists.artist", statusCodes: NSIndexSet(index: 200))
```

What i want to do is to take for example small image url and map it to my Artist class url property.

I did something like that in GSON writing custom deserializers, but here i haven't found how to do it. I do not want to create another class ImageDescription and create array of that in my Artist class.
So how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cheat a little:

Create a pair of accessor methods for a hypothetical array of images property - but don't add a property, just the accessor methods. In the setter, process the array to extract the image you want and store it into your true image property. The array will contain dictionaries that you will need to process.

Now, in your mapping connect the images array key in the JSON to yhe name of the hypothetical property you created the accessor methods for.

Comment: It works, maybe not as clean as in custom deserializer but works very well! Thanks a lot.